# jquery can't disable radio buttons based on select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to disable radio buttons based on dropdown selection.  Here is the code.

```
<form id="" action="" method="get">
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>Test or Exam</th>
        <td>
            <select id="testid" name="testid">
                <option value="1">Blood Pressure</option>
                <option value="2">Cholesterol</option>
                <option value="4">Hearing test</option>
                <option value="5">HIV-AIDS</option>
                <option value="3">TB test</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Test Result</th>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="1"/>Positive
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="2"/>Negative
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I want the script to disable the radio buttons when Blood pressure is chosen.  Here is the script

```
$(funtion(){
            $("#testid").change(
            function(){
                if($(this).val() === "1"){
                    alert("good");
                    $(".testresult").attr("disabled","disabled")
                }else{
                    $(".testresult").removeAttr('disabled')
                }

            })
        })


})
```

Comment: `function` not `funtion`. Also redundant `})`.

Comment: Look at your console (F12 in most browsers)

Answer (score 1):

replace `funtion` by `function` - plus, you are missing a lot of semicolons:

**edit:** and i just found the extra `})` too.
plus i replaced `attr` and `removeAttr` by the more "up to date" `prop` function now:

```
$(function(){
    $("#testid").change(
        function(){
            if($(this).val() == "1"){
                alert("good");
                $(".testresult").prop("disabled", true);
            }else{
                $(".testresult").prop('disabled', false);
            }

      });
});
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/kL1jyx56/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/37ehuxqs/1/

There were some nesting issues in the code. Fixed here:

```
$(function() {
    $("#testid").change(
        function() {
            if ($(this).val() === "1") {
                alert("good");
                $(".testresult").attr("disabled", true)
            } else {
                $(".testresult").attr('disabled', false)
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `function` and you have an extra `})` and considering you  may want the handler to kick in at page load, add `.change()` at the end to trigger `change` when the page loads. And `.prop()` is more preferred than `.attr()` and it makes for much shorter code which is even easier to read.

And in case a previously checked radio  button that remains checked bothers you (it wont be submitted) you can set all to be unchecked by saying so in `.prop()`:

```js
$(function(){
     $("#testid").on('change', function(){
         this.value !== "1" || alert( 'good' );
         $('.testresult').prop({disabled: this.value === "1", checked: false});
     })
     .change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="get">
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>Test or Exam</th>
        <td>
            <select id="testid" name="testid">
                <option value="1">Blood Pressure</option>
                <option value="2">Cholesterol</option>
                <option value="4">Hearing test</option>
                <option value="5">HIV-AIDS</option>
                <option value="3">TB test</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Test Result</th>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="1"/>Positive
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="2"/>Negative
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#testid").on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val() === "1"){
   alert("good");
   $(".testresult").attr("disabled","disabled");
  }else{
   $(".testresult").removeAttr('disabled');
  }

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="" action="" method="get">
<table >
    <tr>
        <th>Test or Exam</th>
        <td>
            <select id="testid" name="testid">
                <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <option value="1">Blood Pressure</option>
                <option value="2">Cholesterol</option>
                <option value="4">Hearing test</option>
                <option value="5">HIV-AIDS</option>
                <option value="3">TB test</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Test Result</th>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="1"/>Positive
            <input type="radio" class="testresult" name="resultid" value="2"/>Negative
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=1> Animal
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=2> Mammal
<input type="radio" name="disableme" id=3> Human
```

and this

```
var radios = document.formName.disableme;

for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
radios[i].disabled = true;
}
```

You don't have to add ID's ;)